# Powermock not intercepting new object creation

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, powermock, easymock

I am attempting to test a method that creates a new instance of another class that I wish to mock using powermock. My code (simplified) is as follows -

Testing code:

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import static org.easymock.EasyMock.anyObject;
import static org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.*;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest( { ClassUnderTest.class } )
public class TestForClassUnderTest {

    private ClassToBeMocked classToBeMocked;
    private ClassUnderTest classUnderTest;

    public void testSimple() throws Exception {

        classToBeMocked = createMock(ClassToBeMocked.class);
        // trying to intercept the constructor
        // I *think* this is the root cause of the issue 
        expectNew(ClassToBeMocked.class, anyObject(), anyObject(), anyObject()).andReturn(classToBeMocked);

        classToBeMocked.close();
        expectLastCall();
        replayAll();

        // call to perform the test
        classUnderTest.doStuff();
    }
}
```

Code that is being tested:

```
import ClassToBeMocked;

public class ClassUnderTest {
    private ClassToBeMocked classToBeMocked;

    public void doStuff() {

        classToBeMocked = new ClassToBeMocked("A","B","C");
        // doing lots of other things here that I feel are irrelevant
        classToBeMocked.close();
    }
}
```

Code that I wish to mock:

```
public class ClassToBeMocked {
    public ClassToBeMocked(String A, String B, String C) {
    // irrelevant
    }
    public close() {
    // irrelevant
    }
}
```

The error I get is as below:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

    at ....more inner details of where this goes into

    at ClassToBeMocked.close

    at ClassUnderTest.doStuff

    at TestForClassUnderTest.test.unit.testSimple

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

PowerMock version:1.4.5

EasyMock version: 3.1

PS: I have stripped down the code to bare minimums, only showing the details of the mocking library, let me know if you think my other code is somehow interfering and I can give more details on the bits you think are important to show. Any links to other examples doing this may even help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized that the reason this wasn't working was because I was extending another class. I had

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest( { ClassUnderTest.class } )
public class TestForClassUnderTest extends AnotherClass {

}
```

as soon as I removed the extends, it worked. Not sure if its just not able to extend another class with powermock or due to AnotherClass, but removing it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

whenever you wish to mock a new instance of any class, you should be doing like this

```
Powermock.expectNew(ClassYouWishToMock.class).andReturn(whateverYouWantToReturn).anyTimes();
Powermock.replayAll();
```

this will return 'whateverYouWantToReturn' whener `new` is called on this class.

but whenever you want to mock a instance variable, you should be using `Whitebox` feature of easymock.

have a look at following Example

```
Class A{
     private B b;
}
```

to mock this my test class will look something like this

```
...//other powermock, easymock class level annotations
@PrepareForTest(B.class)
class ATest{
        Whitebox.setInternalState(B.class,b,whateverValueYouWantYourMockedObjectToReflect);
}
```

here 'b' passed in parameter, is the variable name you want to mock.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thats sort of similar to what I've done though isn't it? I just dont have the .anyTimes() ?

Comment: is your variable an instance variable?I should have seen it earlier

Comment: Sorry which variable? Could you specify maybe with the name?

Comment: In you actual code which you are testing, is object of `ClassToBeMocked ` defined as an instance variable?

Comment: So in my code to be tested, I create a new instance of ClassToBeMocked everytime the test code is run, exactly as shown above - "classToBeMocked = new ClassToBeMocked("A","B","C");"

Comment: i see that, but is that declared as instance variable i.e class variable?

Comment: It is an instance variable yes, and its not static

Comment: I haven't used this before, but I believe the whitebox feature is for accessing internals of a class. I don't see how the whitebox would help with the actual mocking? It seems to be more of a testing feature. If you could elaborate that would be great.

Comment: So I actually found out the reason why it wasn't working was because my main testing class was extending another class. I"m not sure if its just that you cant put this on a class that extends another class or due to the class I was extending, but when I removed it, I was able to mock my objects using powermock! Thanks for all your help!